# Click on one link in geckoWebBrowser in C#

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I want to click on one link in one page.

Here is my code:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//GO
{
    if (!Xpcom.IsInitialized) Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
    geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=67126881188552864");    
}
```

And I want to click on a link:

```
<a href="#" class="violet" onclick="ii.ShowTab(6)">حقیقی-حقوقی</a>
```

can anybody help me?
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I just looked up a Gecko project where I was clicking on the link and while the following might not be the most elegant way the same technique should work for you:

```
private void geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var elements = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
    foreach (GeckoHtmlElement element in elements)
    {
        if (element.ClassName == "violet")
        {
            element.ScrollIntoView(false);
            element.Click();
        }
     }
}
```

I don't think the `ScrollIntoView` call is actually required, I just did that because it was an animated button and I wanted to see it was working. But you will need to wait until the document has loaded before clicking so I've put it in the `DocumentCompleted` event so before the `Navigate` don't forget to add:

```
geckoWebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
```